# How to raise a duplicate question to be voted on?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm not sure if the question has been asked before but I've posted a possible similar solution link in the comment section of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70371900/any-way-to-ignore-certain-lines-when-reading-in-a-sql-file) without initially raising a duplicate flag. The OP did reply  that the link that I provided solve their issue and only after that I raised the duplicate flag. I'm sure that the question should appear in review but I'm wondering, let's say after a few days the question still remain with my one single duplicate vote, how do I raise it for attention?

Comment: *"how do I raise it for attention?"* You don't and id wouldn't even make sense if you could. There is no "close this asap" option and there is no need for one.

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense? Wasn't the goal here is to minimize duplicates? If someone found that question without no answer at all instead and it wasn't linked to any similar question that have the definite answer, won't that lead them to ask another, similar question?

Comment: If you vote to close something, it goes into the close review queue. You've done your part, there's no need to keep watch over it

Comment: You mean if someone reads the question and is unable to read the comments where the duplicate link has been posted?

Comment: "*let's say after a few days the question still remain with my one single duplicate vote, how do I raise it for attention?*" - You could also post on the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (SO Close Vote Reviewers) chat

Comment: @Tom , is it possible that when you raised a duplicate flag and it's been declined, the comment also being removed?

Comment: @FanoFN no, that doesn't happen. 1. There is no "decline" on closures. At most, nobody casts any more close votes and your own vote ages away and is removed. 2. Even if the close vote ages away, the comment remains unless deleted by any other means. It's not automatically removed.

Comment: The dupe comment will only be deleted when the question is closed as a duplicate (not when it is closed of different reason), deleted by yourself or deleted by a mod. So when the question remains open, then you comment should be there indefinitely.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I guess I just raise a flag, move on and probably try my luck in SOCVR then.

Comment: "Wasn't the goal here is to minimise duplicates" - duplicate answers yes. That is a fair point. Minimise does not imply prevent though. Hasty decisions are still not a good idea, it needs to go through the same vetting process as any other closure and that might mean it takes days to handle the flag, or maybe even never. That is all part of the larger problem of there being too much content flowing in. And say that in that timeframe someone does write a duplicate answer... well I don't think anyone will lose sleep. It might even be a better answer, who knows.

Comment: @Gimby There are plenty of dupes on things that have been asked again and again and again and *again*. Some times even a gold badge holder is not able to hammer the Q closed before there are multiple answers that just give out the code directly. I had one instance where I closed a question almost immediately after being posted and ~3 minutes after posting, there were 3 answers that just reiterated something that the dupe already had.

Comment: @Gimby besides, the point of duplicates is to get the knowledge in one place. If there are a couple of good answers against A, then one in B, then one in C, that's a *failure* of gathering all the content in one place.

Comment: I would say it's a failure of the answerer for not finding the duplicate before answering.  Which in turn is partially a failure of Stack Overflow for providing inadequate search, inadequate incentives for closing as a duplicate, and really, inadequate tools around duplicates for every step of the process, for askers, answerers, and curators.

Comment: @HereticMonkey [If I had a magic wand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368077) I'd fix all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is almost never a justification to "raise" or "escalate" a close vote. If you believe that a question should be closed, cast your vote, and leave it at that. There are three possibilities that can follow:

1. The question gets more views, a couple of the new viewers agree with you, and the question is closed.
2. The question gets more views, nobody agrees with your vote, and the vote eventually expires. The rule for close-vote expiry considers both the time since the vote was cast, and the number of views the question has received in that time.
3. The question doesn't get any more views, and your vote lingers forever on a "dead" question.

In all three cases, there isn't a need to escalate the issue. In the first two cases consensus has been reached, and in the third case nobody cares about the question, so it doesn't matter if it is left open or closed. The purpose of closing a question is to prevent new answers. Without views, there won't be any new answers anyway.

In addition, there is a review queue designed to attract more votes on questions that should possibly be closed, so the system does some of the "raising" for you. However, this queue has almost always had more questions than the ones of reviewers could handle, so nowadays there must be good evidence that it really needs closing before a questions is added to it.

Making a meta-post about every question that needs to be closed is just not scalable.

Comment: I understand but to address your last point, I'm asking in general and using that single question as a reference only. One of the main reason I ask was because I had raised duplicate flags before where my votes eventually expires. Some of those have answers but most of them were not with accepted answers. Whether the duplicate (I've linked) resolves the OP's issue or (any of) the answer posted have, I don't know. Maybe I'm just over-thinking it.

Comment: @FanoFN: Yes, ti was clear that you were asking a general question, this isn't a "please close this for me". I only added that point in order to highlight that escalating the issue on meta for each unclosed question one thinks should be closed is not a viable option. Regarding the expiry of the votes, maybe people didn't think the duplicate was correct, or more likely no one ever saw the question again. You mentioned that they had answers, but I assume they were posted before your vote, so closing them wouldn't really achieve much, since the comment is there to point to the canonical.